# Navigating to next page in Selenium IDE.

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

On the web application i am currently working on, there is a button. When i click on that button using selenium IDE, IDE doesnot record the click. I clicked the button using button id/css/xpath, it clicks on it but doesnot get to the new page that it is supposed to. However it manages to complete the next scripts and passes the test.

Comment: Please post the code and what output/error you get after executing the code. It would help even better if you can post the HTML of the button you are clicking.

Comment: Without your code like @Sham said we can't help you.

Comment: <div class="actions pmc-wizard-actions">

    <button id="pmc_wizard_prev" class="btn btn-prev"> … </button>
    <button id="pmc_wizard_next" class="btn btn-next" data-last="Submit"> … </button>

</div>

Comment: This is the html on the button i am trying to access. I have tried xpaths, locating via id and name and css too. When i click find on selenium IDE it highlights it too.

Comment: I don't get any error. it just doesn't navigate to the next page, although it does perform all the actions i require on the next page and the test case passes.

Comment: which button are you trying to click?  I see two different button id's in the code you submitted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Selenium Advanced UI Interactions to click on the button.